# Input Field is losing focus while typing (AJAX Search)

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome

I've an issue that i couldn't solve by myself. I have made a search input with ajax that suggest results while typing. The script works properly with Firefox but when I use it on chrome the input field loses the focus while typing.

Here is the Code:

```
//Gets the browser specific XmlHttpRequest Object
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {

        alert("Please update your Browser");
    }
}

//Our XmlHttpRequest object to get the auto suggest
var searchReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

//Called from keyup on the search textbox.
//Starts the AJAX request.
function searchSuggest() {
    if (searchReq.readyState == 4 || searchReq.readyState == 0) {
        var str = encodeURI(document.getElementById('campo-search-
        modal
        ').value);

        searchReq.open("GET", 'https://mywebsite.com/search.php?search=' + str, true);
        searchReq.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest;
        searchReq.send(null);

    }
}

//Called when the AJAX response is returned.
function handleSearchSuggest() {
    if (searchReq.readyState == 4) {
        var ss = document.getElementById('cont-list-re-search')
        ss.innerHTML = '';
        if (document.getElementById('campo-search-modal').value.length > 2) {
            var str = searchReq.responseText.split("\n");
            for (i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
                //Build our element string.  This is cleaner using the DOM, but
                //IE doesn't support dynamically added attributes.
                var suggest = '<li ';
                suggest += 'class="suggest_link">' + str[i] + '</li>';
                ss.innerHTML += suggest;
            }
        }
        else {
            ss.innerHTML = 'Perfavore inserire almeno 3 caratteri!';

        }
    }
}

//Mouse over function
function suggestOver(div_value) {
    div_value.className = 'suggest_link_over';
}

//Mouse out function
function suggestOut(div_value) {
    div_value.className = 'suggest_link';
}

//Click function
function setSearch(value) {
    document.getElementById('campo-search-modal').value = value;
    document.getElementById('cont-list-re-search').innerHTML = '';
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group row row-camp-search">

<div class="col-5">
<input class="form-control modal-search" type="search" id="campo-search-
modal" placeholder="Ricerca Nel Sito..." onKeyUp="searchSuggest();">

</div>
</div>
</form>   

 <div id="result-search">
<ul id="cont-list-re-search">

 </ul>
```

The use types inside the input, and an ajax call is made. I didn't include the php search page because there are just queries to database and the circles to print the results.

The odd thing is that this script works well with Firefox but when used on Google Chrome the input field loses focus. Even after the first letter.

PHP:

```
$search = $_GET["search"]; 
if(!empty($search))
{



try {

$connes = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME", $DB_USER, 
$DB_PASS);
$connes->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmtb = $connes->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col like('%" . 
simple_protect($search) . "%') ORDER BY col LIMIT 2"); 

    $stmtb->execute();

    $resulta = $stmtb->fetchAll();

 }
catch(PDOException $b) {
echo "Error: " . $b->getMessage();
}
$connes = null; 
if($resulta && count($resulta) > 0)
            {
foreach($resulta as $key => $row)
                    {
echo '<a href="https://website.com/scheda/index.php?
dettagli='.strip_all($row['nome']).'"><div class="img-res-search" 
style="background-image:url(https://website.com/img/miniature/min-
'.strip_all($row['icona']).')"></div><div class="tit-res-
search">'.strip_all($row['nome']).'</div></a><div class="dett-res-search">
<div class="dett1-res-search"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true">
</i>'.strip_all($row['voto']).'</div><div class="dett2-res-search">
<i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i>Section</div></div>'."\n";
 }}
}
else
{
echo "Nessun Risultato!";
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is basically irrelevant (except for the fact that you tagged this Q with jQuery, which would shorten that code to a fraction, but aren't using it). You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's not sufficient that code you've shared here.  Further, where is the jquery code?

Comment: edited with the full code, i hope this may help. Sorry but is the first time that i use stackoverflow :(

Comment: It seems you test the length of the field in the wrong function. `function searchSuggest() { var val = document.getElementById('campo-search-
        modal').value; if (val.length>2) { searchReq.open("GET", 'https://mywebsite.com/search.php?search=' + encodeURIComponent(str), true); ...`

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test to try to emulate the issue with your original code but I was unable to replicate the issue you mentioned with Chrome - it worked fine in both Chrome and Firefox after correcting the syntax error ( probably just due to copy/paste here ) apart from the checking of the field value string length. The test for string length should be before you make the ajax call ( as was noted in a comment ) rather than within the callback function.

The issue:

```
encodeURI(document.getElementById('campo-search-
        modal
        ').value);
```

With the ID on multiple lines like this it threw nasty little errors.

I then ended up quickly rewriting this as below, some of which may be of interest.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>ajax search suggestions</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                /* ultra basic ajax function */
                function ajax( url, callback ){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response );
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'GET', url, true );
                    xhr.send( null );
                }

                /* onkeyup event handler */
                function searchSuggest( event ) {
                    var ss = document.getElementById('cont-list-re-search');
                    var callback=function(r){
                        ss.innerHTML = '';
                        var str = r.split("\n");
                        for( var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++ ) {
                            /* use DOM methods rather than string concatenation */
                            var li=document.createElement('li');
                                li.className='suggest_link';
                                li.innerHTML=str[i];
                            ss.appendChild( li );
                        }
                        /* bring focus back to form field */
                        this.focus();
                    };
                    /* Check length of input data BEFORE sending ajax request */
                    if( event.target.value.length > 2 ){
                        ajax.call( this, 'search.php?search='+event.target.value, callback.bind( event.target ) );
                    } else {
                        ss.innerHTML = 'Perfavore inserire almeno 3 caratteri!';
                    }   
                }

                /* assign event handler */
                document.getElementById('campo-search-modal').onkeyup=searchSuggest;
            }, false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class='form-group row row-camp-search'>
                <div class='col-5'>
                    <input class='form-control modal-search' type='text' id='campo-search-modal' placeholder='Ricerca Nel Sito...' /><!-- removed inline event handler -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id='result-search'>
        <ul id='cont-list-re-search'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you i'm going to try it now and i'll leti you know :)

Comment: i've just done the test and until you insert the third character (the minumum characters needed to print the results) it works now but it seems that every time it finds some result the input field still lose the focus....i dind't mantioned before that the input filed is inside a bootstrap modal..

Comment: One could call the `focus` method within the callback function if that is a problem

Comment: i already tried to do that but it doesn't work... the strange thing is that in firefox it works well...it gives problems just with chrome :(

Comment: very odd - it works fine with both FF & Chrome here. Nevermind, Happy New Year and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this prevails on Chrome, especially on Windows. Works fine in other machines.

You can solve it easily by removing '**tab-index = -1**' from modal of Bootstrap. This will solve your issue of losing focus on ajax calls.

One downside, Esc will not work anymore to lose focus and modal close.